# In HTML5, can the <header> and <footer> tags appear outside of the <body> tag?

Tags: html, tags

I'm currently using the above tags in this way (classic tag order):

```
<html>
  <head>...</head>
  <body>
    <header>...</header>
    <section>...</section>
    <footer>...</footer>
  </body>
</html>
```

Tag usage and specifications were very rigid in previous versions of HTML (4.x), while HTML5 doesn't really need `<head>` and even `<body>` tags.

So I would use the following structure, which IMHO is much more semantic than the previous one.

```
<html>
  <header>...</header>     <!-- put header and footer outside the body tag -->
  <body>
    <section>...</section>
    <section>...</section>
    <section>...</section>
  </body>
  <footer>...</footer>
</html>
```

What do you think?

Comment: HTML5 is forgiving, but not _that_ forgiving. the fact that you already include a BODY element, redundantly declare the BODY then close the BODY before the inclusion of FOOTER renders this invalid, I believe. There are lots of nice "implicits" with HTML5, but improperly terminating elements is going to sting you

Comment: The rules over the presence and absence of the `head` and `body` tags is exactly the same in HTML5 as it is in HTML 4.x. In fact, they're exactly the same as they were in HTML 2.0. Only XHTML is different.

Answer (score 55):

Well, the `<head>` tag has nothing to do with the `<header>` tag. In the `head` comes all the metadata and stuff, while the `header` is just a layout component.
And layout comes into `body`. So I disagree with you.

Comment: I agree with @iuliux, all display content should be in the `<body>`, so `<header>` and `<footer>` should always be inside there. Like he said `<head>` is just for metadata

Comment: Yup. `<body>` means the body of the HTML document, i.e. the entirety of what the browser is expected to render. “More semantic” means more meaningful, and whilst your idea might be more meaningful to you (and indeed others), it’s not the meaning agreed in the HTML spec.

Answer (score 31):

Let's get a canonical answer here. I will reference the [HTML5 spec](http://whatwg.org/html).

First of all, [12.1.2.4 Optional tags](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/syntax.html#optional-tags):

> A `head` element's *start tag* may be omitted if the element is empty, or if the first thing inside the `head` element is an element.
>
> A `head` element's *end tag* may be omitted if the `head` element is not immediately followed by a *space character* or a *comment*.
>
> A `body` element's *start tag* may be omitted if the element is empty, or if the first thing inside the `body` element is not a *space character* or a *comment*, except if the first thing inside the `body` element is a `script` or `style` element.
>
> A `body` element's *end tag* may be omitted if the `body` element is not immediately followed by a *comment*.

Then, the [4.1.1 The html element](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/semantics.html#the-html-element):

> **Content model:** A `head` element followed by a `body` element.

Having the cited restrictions and strictly defined element order, we can easily work out what are the rules for placing implicit `<body>` tag.

Since `<head/>` must come first, and it can contain elements only (and not direct text), all elements suitable for `<head/>` will become the part of implicit `<head/>`, up to the first stray text or `<body/>`-specific element. At that moment, all remaining elements and text nodes will be placed in `<body/>`.

---

Now let's consider your second snippet:

```
<html>
  <header>...</header>
  <body>
    <section>...</section>
    <section>...</section>
    <section>...</section>
  </body>
  <footer>...</footer>
</html>
```

Here, the `<header/>` element is not suitable for `<head/>` (it's *flow content*), the `<body>` tag will be placed immediately before it. In other words, the document will be understood by browser as following:

```
<html>
  <head/>
  <body>
    <header>...</header>
    <body>
      <section>...</section>
      <section>...</section>
      <section>...</section>
    </body>
    <footer>...</footer>
  </body>
</html>
```

And that's certainly *not* what you were expecting. And as a note, it is invalid as well; see [4.4.1 The body element](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/sections.html#the-body-element):

> **Contexts in which this element can be used:** As the second element in an `html` element.
>
> [...]
>
> In conforming documents, there is only one `body` element.

---

Thus, the `<header/>` or `<footer/>` *will* be correctly used in this context. Well, they will be practically equivalent to the first snippet. But this will cause an additional `<body/>` element in middle of a `<body/>` which is invalid.

---

As a side note, you're probably confusing `<body/>` here with [the main part of the content](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/common-idioms.html#the-main-part-of-the-content) which has no specific element. You could look up that page for other solutions on getting what you want.

Quoting [4.4.1 The body element](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/sections.html#the-body-element) once again:

> The `body` element represents the main content of the document.

which means *all* the content. And both header and footer are part of this content.

Comment: If you can add a TL;DR and add in a conclusion to the original question title 'does header and footer need to be in the body' that would be helpful. I'm guessing you are saying in your last sentence that yes, the body and footer do need to be in the body tag.

Answer (score 20):

I see what you are trying to do, you are trying to use the `<body>` tag as the container for the main content of the page. Instead, use the [`<main>` tag](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/main), as specified in the HTML5 spec. I use this layout:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
    <html>
        <head> *Metadata* </head>
        <body>
            <header>
                *<h1> and other important stuff </h1>*
                <nav> *Usually a formatted <Ul>* </nav>
            </header>
            <main> *All my content* </main>
            <footer> *Copyright, links, social media etc* </footer>
        </body>
    </html>
```

I'm not 100% sure but I think that anything outside the `<body>` tag is considered metadata and will not be rendered by the browser. I don't think that the DOM can access it either.

To conclude, use the `<main>` tag for your content and keep formatting your HTML the correct way as you have in your first code snippet. You used the `<section>` tag but I think that comes with some weird formatting issues when you try to apply CSS.

Comment: The main element is only partly supported in IE [Can i use it](http://caniuse.com/#feat=html5semantic)

Comment: Correct. According to the link you gave it was added late to the specification and we all know how differently IE handles common specifications. Thanks for pointing that out!

Answer (score 11):

If you really want it to look more semantic like having the `<body>` in the middle you can use the `<main>` element. With all the recent advances the `<body>`element is not as semantic as it once was but you just have to think of it as a wrapper in which the view port sees.

```
<html>
    <head>
    </head>
    <body>
        <header>
        </header>
        <main>
            <section></section>
            <article></article>
        </main>
        <footer>
        </footer>
    <body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 3):

[According to the HTML standard](http://www.whatwg.org/specs/web-apps/current-work/multipage/semantics.html#the-html-element-0), the content model of the HTML element is:

> A head element followed by a body
>   element.

You can either define the BODY element in the source code:

```
<html>
    <body>
        ... web-page ...
    </body>
</html>
```

or you can omit the BODY element:

```
<html>
    ... web-page ...
</html>
```

However, it is invalid to place the BODY element inside the web-page content (in-between other  elements or text content), like so:

```
<html>
    ... content ...
    <body>
        ... content ...
    </body>
    ... content ...
</html>
```

Comment: No, actually it won't. The inner body element won't exist. The explicit body tags are effectively ignored (although the implicitly created body element adopts any attributes on the start tag). See here: http://software.hixie.ch/utilities/js/live-dom-viewer/?%3C!DOCTYPE%20html%3E%0A%3Chtml%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%3Cheader%3E...%3C%2Fheader%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%3Cbody%20id%3D%22x%22%3E...%3C%2Fbody%3E%0A%20%20%20%20%3Cfooter%3E...%3C%2Ffooter%3E%0A%3C%2Fhtml%3E%0A

Comment: @Alohci You're right. This behavior is even cross-browser. This is interesting because the HTML code is invalid.

Answer (score 2):

I agree with some of the others' answers. The `<head>` and `<header>` tags have two unique and very unrelated functions. The `<header>` tag, if I'm not mistaken, was introduced in HTML5 and was created for increased accessibility, namely for screen readers. It's generally used to indicate the heading of your document and, in order to work appropriately and effectively, should be placed inside the `<body>` tag. The `<head>` tag, since it's origin, is used for SEO in that it constructs all of the necessary meta data and such. A valid HTML structure for your page with both tags included would be like something like this:

```
<!DOCTYPE html/>
<html lang="es">
    <head>
        <!--crazy meta stuff here-->
    </head>
    <body>
        <header>
            <!--Optional nav tag-->
            <nav>
            </nav>
        </header>
        <!--Body content-->
    </body>
</html>
```

Comment: Almost.  The header element provides semantic value, one of many such elements added in HTML5.

Comment: `<pedantic>`"*...is used for SEO in that it constructs all of the necessary meta data...*" -- I'd say this is backwards; `<head>` is meant for metadata, which *may* be SEO-oriented. `</pedantic>`

Answer (score 1):

This is the general structure of an html document.

```
<html>
    <head>
        Title, meta-data, scripts, etc go here... Don't confuse with header
    </head>
    <body>
        You body stuff comes here...
        <footer>
            Your footer stuff goes here...
        </footer>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

Even though the `<head>` and `<body>` *tags* aren't required, the elements are still there - it's just that the browser can work out where the tags would have been from the rest of the document.

The other elements you're using still have to be inside the `<body>`