# How do I stop my 'body' from eating my 'foot'

Tags: html, css, footer

Here is my site: http://mytestsite.nfshost.com/.

If you make your browser window thinner, you'll notice that the content in the page's 'body' tag overtakes the 'footer' element. Instead, I'd like it to merely push the 'footer' content down without engulfing it.

How do I do that?

Below are the relevant sections from the HTML and CSS.

```
<html>
    <head>
        -- HEAD CONTENT HERE --
    </head>
    <body>
        <h1>U.S. Neighborhood Income Map</h1>
        <h2>See how rich or poor every part of every city in America is</h2>
        <div id="address-form-container">
            <span id="form-pretext"> Enter a city name or address and pick a state (Or just a pick a state from the dropdown).</span>
            <br>
            <input id="address" type="textbox">
            ,
            <select id="state-select">
            <input type="button" value="Search">
            <br>
            <span id="note">(NOTE: If loading takes a while, try zooming in or out.)</span>
        </div>
        <div id="map-canvas" style="position: relative; background-color: rgb(229, 227, 223); overflow: hidden;">
            -- MAP HERE --
        </div>
        <div id="below-map">
            <p id="source-note" class="italics">
        </div>
    </body>
    <footer>
        <p id="contact">Please send all questions, comments, complaints, and suggestions to [EMAIL ADDRESS]</p>
    </footer>
</html>
```

Here's the relevant CSS

```
html {
    float: right;
    height: 100%;
    text-align: center;
    width: 100%;
}

body {
    background:url(./images/bg.png);
    height: 85%;
    position: relative;
    right: 8px;
    width: 100%;

}

#map-canvas {
    height: 75%;
    margin-top: 5px;
    width: 100%;
}

footer {
    margin-top: 3em;
}
```

Comment: This might be the funniest question title I've seen on SO.

Comment: That's probably the most gruesome title I've yet seen on Stack Overflow.

Comment: The footer has to be inside the body tag.

Comment: @alex2php, please undelete you answer... it is the correct one.

Comment: Yeah, see [this related question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/5492492/781965)

Comment: Why on earth do you `float` the `html` tag ?!?

Comment: Expect some reply referring to your <head>  ;-)

Comment: And maybe an eating / table comment?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

footer must be inside body tag.

Comment: Thanks, that worked. Though, I thought the 'footer' tag was "allowed" (for lack of a better word) to be outside the body. Is what I thought incorrect? If so, I wonder why it isn't allowed outside the body...

Comment: `body` contains the whole of the data that make up the visual page. outside it there is only the `head` which is for the *metadata*. See http://stackoverflow.com/q/5492492/781965 as noted by @jeff

Comment: Hm, seems like it might confuse people -- to me, at least. I mean, 'head' is allowed outside the 'body', so why not 'footer'? Well, anyways, at least now I know. Thanks.

Comment: According to http://dev.w3.org/html5/markup/footer.html#footer, the footer *must* have a parent which supports flow elements. The html tag does not.

Comment: [`head`](http://www.w3.org/wiki/HTML/Elements/head) is not [`header`](http://www.w3.org/wiki/HTML/Elements/header).

Comment: Ah, I forgot about the 'header' tag. I guess for my idea to work, there would have to be a 'foot' tag. Thanks again, @GabyakaG.Petrioli

Answer (score 1):

use css padding

```
footer {
    padding-top: 25px;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Create a division with `class = "clear"`

css

```
div.clear {
     clear:both
}
```

Use this above any division that you want to push down as page content grows. Also footer must be in body tag as Alex stated.