# Why did web developers stop using the <footer> html element?

Tags: html

I've noticed that a lot of sites these days do not include a `footer` element.

Typically you would expect to see something like:

```
<html>
 <head>
 </head>
 <body>
 </body>
 <footer>
 </footer>
</html>
```

However, I'm finding that most websites do not contain any `footer` element anymore and stick everything right before the body closes. Why are they doing this?

Comment: a footer outside the body?????

Comment: Footer should always be in `<body>` tag. [relevant question.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5492492/in-html5-can-the-header-and-footer-tags-appear-outside-of-the-body-tag)

Comment: I'm voting to close this question as off-topic because it's based on the false assumption that the <footer> element was ever meant to be used outside the <body> element.

Answer (score 2):

The `<html>` is only meant to contain 2 elements: `<head>`, which contains information about the page that is not included in the displayed page (e.g. the title, metadata); and `<body>`, which contains the contents of the page, as it is displayed in your browser.

Within the `<body>` tag, you can find "typical" elements such as `<div>`, `<h1>`, `<img>`, etc. and more semantic elements from HTML5, such as `<header>`, `<footer>`, `<section>`.

Whether those semantic elements are used is up to the developer/designer that built the website, but it is recommended that they be used.