# Using Javascript to add a sidebar and change padding on some HTML pages

Tags: javascript, html, css

This may be something simple, but I am a total noob with javascript and pretty green with HTML, so I would appreciate a hand with this.

I have a very simple website I am hosting on a home server where I blog about my two favorite hobbies; books and travel. I am using a CSS referenced by all the pages on my site for their layout, and I have a simple javascript that adds a footer, and a top navigation menu. I like this method because it makes adding buttons to the top navigation pane super simple in the future without having to touch each separate page. I would like to add a sidebar to *some* pages using the same methodology, and I have successfully managed to do so. But with this method, I find that I need to adjust the padding of the body of (only) those pages I add the sidebar to by a number of pixels so the sidebar doesn't just meld into the text/images in the body. I thought adding,

```
document.getElementById("nav03").style.padding = "5px 5px 5px 215px";
```

to my script would do the trick, but I was sort of mistaken. the padding seems to be affecting my sidebar, not the body of the page I put the "nav03" call on. Ideally, I would like the padding change to take place with the "sidebar" addition to the page and not have to have two separate calls, but I split it into the nav03 just for testing to eliminate the possibility that the code adding the sidebar may somehow be interfering with my goal. Below is my CSS, the javascript, and a sample of a page I would like to add the sidebar to if anyone could point me in the right direction. This may not be the best way to add a sidebar I am sure, but it is comfortable for me and seems like it would be easy to make changes to in the future the same way the top navigation menu works.

```js
document.getElementById("foot01").innerHTML =
"<p>&copy;  " + new Date().getFullYear() + " codyfair.kicks-ass.net. All rights reserved.</p>";
document.getElementById("topnav").innerHTML =
"<ul id='topnav'>" +
"<li><a href='index.html'>Home</a></li>" +
"<li><a href='codystravels'>Cody's Travels</a></li>" +
"<li><a href='codyssietch'>The Sietch</a></li>" +
"<li><a href='codysworkshop'>The Workshop</a></li>" +
"</ul>"; 
document.getElementById("sidebar").innerHTML =
"<ul id='sidebar'>" +
"<li><a href='archivedhikes'>Archived Hikes</a></li>" +
"<li><a href='archivedreviews'>Archived Reviews</a></li>" +
"<li><a href='codyssietch'>The Sietch</a></li>" +
"<li><a href='codysworkshop'>The Workshop</a></li>" +
"</ul>";
document.getElementById("nav03").style.padding = "5px 5px 5px 215px";
```

```css
body {
    font-family: "Lucida Sans Unicode", Verdana, sans-serif;
    font-size: 16px;
    background-color: dimgrey;
    color: #000000;
    padding: 3px;
}

a:link    {color:green; background-color:transparent; text-decoration:underline}
a:visited {color:dimgrey; background-color:transparent; text-decoration:none}
a:hover   {color:red; background-color:transparent; text-decoration:underline}
a:active  {color:yellow; background-color:transparent; text-decoration:underline}

#main {
    padding: 5px;
    padding-left:  15px;
 padding-right: 5px;
    background-color: linen;
    border-radius: 0 0 5px 5px;
}

h1 {
    font-family: Georgia, serif;
    border-bottom: 3px solid dimgrey;
    color: dimgrey;
    font-size: 30px;
}
h2 {
    font-family: Georgia, serif;
    color: dimgrey;
    font-size: 20px;
 
}
ul#topnav {
    padding: 0;
    margin-bottom: 11px;
}

ul#topnav li {
    display: inline;
    margin-right: 3px;
}

ul#topnav li a {
    background-color: linen;
    padding: 10px 20px;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #696969;
    border-radius: 4px 4px 0 0;
}

ul#topnav li a:hover {
    color: white;
    background-color: black;
} 
ul#sidebar {
    position:absolute;
 top: 60px;
 left: 0;
 bottom: 0;
 height: 100%
}

ul#sidebar li {
    margin-right: 3px;
}

ul#sidebar li a {
    background-color: linen;
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #696969;
    border-radius: 0px 0px 0 0;
}

ul#sidebar li a:hover {
    color: white;
    background-color: black;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>

<head>
<title>The Sietch</title>
<link href="cfdesign.css" rel="stylesheet">
</head>

<nav id="topnav"></nav>
<nav id="sidebar"></nav>
<nav id="nav03"></nav>

<body>

<div id="main">

<h1>Currently Reading:</h1>

<p><img src="pics/reading.JPG" align="right"></p>

<p><a href="codyssietch"><i>Einstein: His Life and Universe</i> by Walter Isaacson</a>
    
<h1><a href="animalfarmreview">The Ten Books You Should Be Beaten For Not Having Read Yet</a></h1>

There are some books you encounter in life that are so moving, so relatable, that they touch you deeply, almost 
in the same way a special love would. In many cases you become so attached, that you are almost offended when others have not read these books, or worse yet, 
have never heard of them. I am easily offended in this regard, so check out my top ten list, and then go read them! Each book on this list is of course a solid 5 stars.
    
<h1>Recently Reviewed</h1>

<p>Click each title to read my review, and see my 1-5 star rating.</p>

<h2><a href="spqrreview"><i>S.P.Q.R. A History of Ancient Rome</i> by Mary Beard</a></h2>
<h2><a href="bobbyfischergoestowarreview"><i>Bobby Fischer Goes to War: How the Soviets Lost the Most Extraordinary Chess Match of All Time</i> by David Edmonds & John Eidinow</a></h2>
<h2><a href="thethreemusketeersreview"><i>The Three Musketeers</i> by Alexandre Dumas</a></h2>

<h1>Archived Reviews</h1> 
<p><a href="archivedreviews">Click Here for Archived Book Reviews by Year</a></p>

<footer id="foot01"></footer>
</div>

<script src="script.js"></script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: Someone correct me if I'm wrong, but you really shouldn't put markup (specifically the navs) outside of the Body.  That being said - if I'm following you correctly, you really only need to adjust the padding to <div id="main"> - or am I wrong here?

Comment: I did try moving the nav calls inside the body, specifically the padding one, but that made no difference. I don't want to adjust the padding in the CSS because then it would apply to all pages, and I only want it on the pages that are going to have the sidebar.

Comment: It probably wouldn't but you don't want to keep those elements outside of the body. I think that the way HTML5 works would lead to you having an extra, nested body tag auto-generated. Similar to the answer on [this post](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5492492/in-html5-can-the-header-and-footer-tags-appear-outside-of-the-body-tag)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

First, you should really keep your nav's inside of the `body` tag.

That being said - the padding isn't effecting the body because you're targeting the nav03 ID.

Instead, target the "main" id:

```
document.getElementById("main").style.padding = "5px 5px 5px 215px";
```

I believe this is the result you are looking for:

[Fiddle](https://jsfiddle.net/d5h0r5ej/)

**EDIT**

This may effect all pages - which would **not** be the result you're looking for.  You may want to keep the side-nav script in another file and only include it for pages that will render the side-nav.

Comment: Dan, when I first saw your reply, I thought the same thing you said in your edit, wouldn't this affect every page? But when I tried it, it doesn't, it only seems to affect pages that have the sidebar nav tag added, so it is perfect!

Comment: As far as the nav calls within the body tag, would that just be like, a future-proofing sort of thing? I was vaguely aware HTML5 was coming out, but I wasn't sure if it is already the standard now, or if it will be soon, or what?  It does seem to work fine on every browser I have tested my site with currently, but if that would mess something up in the future, I would be interested to know if there are any other design flaws anyone sees that could wreck me one day? Thanks a lot for the help everyone!

Comment: I'd say it's more of a past-proofing sort of thing.  Modern browsers will automatically correct these things, however, the older ones aren't as smart.  General rule of thumb, anything that will be displayed on the page should be contained in the body tag.

Comment: I see, thanks for the tip! Having checked my production server, everything is within the body on my current setup, I must've just moved them on my test machine while testing to see if that made any difference. Very green, so lots of trial and error-mostly error, lol. I am still a little uncertain as to why targeting the "main" id doesn't seem to affect all the pages considering they all call that script for the top navigation... but it works the way I wanted, so I won't look a gift horse in the mouth!

Comment: I'm wondering if other pages are cached and that's why it's currently displaying correctly.  I am still playing around because I believe there's a CSS solution I'm not thinking of.  But, if you do get an adverse effect you can always keep the sidenav code in a separate script.  Not ideal - but a solution nonetheless.