# html - full screen landing page with navbar

Tags: html, css

Testing out full screen landing page, and I got it working for the most part, but I run into issues when I add a navbar above the section container for the image. You have to scroll more than you would than when if the navbar wasn't present to see the content.

Any way to resolve this?

```css
* {
  box-sizing: border-box;
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}

html,
body {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background: #1F2121
}

#top-nav {
  background: #1F2121;
  border-bottom: 4px solid #FFD700;
}

#bot-nav {
  background: #1F2121;
  border-top: 4px solid #FFD700;
}

#copyright {
  background: #FFD700;
}

#bot-nav ul {
  list-style: none;
  padding: 0;
}

#copyright a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #1F2121;
}

header section {
  display: flex;
  height: 90px;
  width: 500px;
  border-left: 1px solid #FFD700;
  border-right: 1px solid #FFD700;
}

#top-nav section a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #FFD700;
  display: inline-flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

#top-nav section a:hover {
  color: #1F2121;
  background-color: #FFD700;
}

.center-section {
  display: flex;
  width: 1000px;
  margin: auto;
}

.center-section>* {
  flex: 1 1 0;
}

.navbar {
  display: flex;
}

.navbar ul {
  list-style-type: none;
  padding: 0;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: row;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100%;
  align-self: center;
}

.navbar ul li {
  display: flex;
  flex: 1 1 100%;
}

.navbar ul li a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #FFD700;
  display: inline-flex;
  align-items: center;
  justify-content: center;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  border-right: 1px solid #FFD700;
}

.navbar ul li a:hover {
  color: #1F2121;
  background-color: #FFD700;
}

.bot-list {
  padding: 20px 0px;
}

.bot-list ul li a {
  text-decoration: none;
  color: #FFD700;
}

.landing {
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  background: url('../images/gold-grid.png') no-repeat 50% 50%;
  background-size: cover;
}

.article {
  padding: 30px 0px;
  color: #FFD700;
}

.copyright-container {
  width: 1000px
}
```

```html
<header>
  <div id="top-nav">
    <div class="center-section">
      <section id="logo">
        <a href="">Home Logo</a>
      </section>
      <div class="navbar">
        <ul>
          <li>
            <a href="">About</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="">Store</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="">Contact</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
</header>

<body id="main-content">
  <section class="landing">
  </section>
  <p class="article">
    Lorem Ipsum is simply dummy text of the printing and typesetting industry. Lorem Ipsum has been the industry's standard dummy text ever since the 1500s, when an unknown printer took a galley of type and scrambled it to make a type specimen book. It has
    survived not only five centuries, but also the leap into electronic typesetting, remaining essentially unchanged. It was popularised in the 1960s with the release of Letraset sheets containing Lorem Ipsum passages, and more recently with desktop publishing
    software like Aldus PageMaker including versions of Lorem Ipsum.
  </p>
</body>

<footer>
  <div id="bot-nav">
    <div class="center-section">
      <div class="bot-list">
        <ul>
          <li>
            <a href="">About</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="">Store</a>
          </li>
          <li>
            <a href="">Contact</a>
          </li>
        </ul>
      </div>
    </div>
  </div>
  <div id="copyright">
    <div copyright-container>
      <p>&copy Flex Test</p>
      <p>Designed by
        <a href="">Incredible Flex Inc.</a>
      </p>
    </div>
  </div>
</footer>
```

Comment: Try `height: calc( 100% - 94px );` on the .landing div. Is that the desired effect?

Comment: Incidentally, `<header>` and `<footer>` should be inside `<body>`. See [In HTML5, can the <header> and <footer> tags appear outside of the <body> tag?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5492492/in-html5-can-the-header-and-footer-tags-appear-outside-of-the-body-tag)

Comment: Thanks, that worked, i didn't consider the calc function. And thanks for pointing out the `<header>` and `<footer>` issues.