# I think my monitor size it too big so my header doesnt fill the full screen

Tags: html, css

I'm currently not home right now and I'm on a smaller monitor working on my website, I noticed that on my monitor back home I checked my website and I noticed that my header width doesn't fill out the entire screen even though my width is 100%, are there any ways to fix this? To be more clear it looks like the width doesn't fully complete each side of my screen.

HTML

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <link href="https://unpkg.com/ionicons@4.5.10-0/dist/css/ionicons.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css1/styler.css">
    <script src="javascript/script.js" defer></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.15.3/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-SZXxX4whJ79/gErwcOYf+zWLeJdY/qpuqC4cAa9rOGUstPomtqpuNWT9wdPEn2fk" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Montserrat&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <header>
        <div style="background-color: #1E90FF;" class="container">
            <nav>
                <div class="menu-icons">
                    <i class="fas fa-bars"></i>
                </div>
                <a href="index.php" class="logo">
                    <img class="logo" src="images/logo_trans.png" alt="logo" style="height: 75px;">
                </a>
                <ul class="nav-list">
                    <li>
                        <a href="#">Home</a>
                    </li>

                    <li>
                        <a href="#">Services
                            <i class="fas fa-sort-down"></i>
                        </a>
                        <ul class="sub-menu">
                            <li>
                                <a href="#">Business Printing</a>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <a href="#">Canvas Printing</a>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <a href="#">Embroidery</a>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <a href="#">Signs</a>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>

                    <li>
                        <a href="#">Partners</a>
                    </li>

                    <li>
                        <a href="#">About Us</a>
                    </li>
                    
                    <li>
                        <a href="#">Contact Us</a>
                    </li>
                    
                    <li class="move-right">
                        <img class="cart" style="float: right;" src="images/new_cart.png" alt="Cart">
                    </li>
                    
                
                </ul>
            </nav>
        </div>
    </header>
    <script src="javascript/script.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
```

CSS

```
*, *::before, *::after {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
    overflow-x: hidden;
}

html {
    font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
    font-size: 12px;
}

a {
    text-decoration: none;
}

ul {
    list-style: none;
}

header {
    width: 100%;
    position: sticky;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 999;
}

.container {
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 117rem;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 0 1.5rem;
}

.menu-icons{
    color: #eee;
    font-size: 4rem;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    right: 2rem;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
    cursor: pointer;
    z-index: 1500;
    display: none;
}

nav {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    width: 100%;
    height: 8rem;
    border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(225,225,225, 0.1);
}

.logo {
    display: flex;
    margin-right: 5rem;
}

.nav-list {
    display: flex;
    width: 100%;
    align-items: center;
}

.nav-list li {
    line-height: 8rem;
    position: relative;
}

.sub-menu li {
    line-height: 4rem;
}

.nav-list a {
    display: block;
    color: white;
    background-color: #1E90FF;
    padding: 0 1.5rem;
    font-size: 1.4rem;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    transition: color 650ms;
    transition: background-color 650ms;
}

.nav-list a:hover {
    color: black;
    background-color: yellow;
}

.cart {
    height: 30px;
    width: 40px;
    cursor: pointer;
    margin-right: 15px;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
}

.btn {
    padding: 1.3rem;
    display: inline-block;
    background-color: #1E90FF;
    border: 2px solid #1E90FF;
    border-radius: 5rem;
    transition: background-color 650ms;
}

.btn:hover {
    color: black;
    background-color: yellow;
}

.sub-menu {
    width: 20rem;
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    border-top: 3px solid #00BFFF;
    z-index: 100;
    top: 16rem;
    transition: all 650ms ease;
    opacity: 0;
    visibility: hidden;
}

.sub-menu::before {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    top: -2.5rem;
    left: 3rem;
    border: 1.2rem solid transparent;
    border-bottom-color: #00BFFF;
}

.sub-menu .sub-menu::before {
    top: .9rem;
    left: -2.5rem;
    border: 1.2rem solid transparent;
    border-right-color: #00BFFF;
}

.sub-menu .sub-menu{
    border-top: none;
    border-left: 3px solid #00BFFF;
    top: 0;
    left: 160%;
}

.nav-list li:hover > .sub-menu {
    top: 8rem;
    opacity: 1;
    visibility: visible;
}

.sub-menu li:hover > .sub-menu {
    top: 0;
    left: 100%;
}
    
li.move-right {
    margin: auto 0 auto auto;
    line-height: initial;
    transition: color 650ms;
    transition: background-color 650ms;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 1050px) {
    .nav-list {
        position: fixed;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        height: 100vh;
        display:none;
        align-items: initial;
        flex-direction: column;
        background-color: #1E90FF;
        z-index: 1000;
        overflow-y: scroll;
    }
    
    .nav-list li {
        line-height: 6rem;
    }
    
    .sub-menu {
        position: initial;
        border: 3px solid transparent;
        border-left-color: #00BFFF;
        margin-left: 1rem;
        max-height: 0;
    }
    
    .sub-menu::before {
        display: none;
    }
    
    .nav-list li:hover > .sub-menu{
        opacity: 1;
        visibility: visible;
        max-height: initial;
    }
    
    li.move-right {
        margin: 0 auto 0 0;
        line-height: initial;
    }
    
    .menu-icons {
        display: block;
    }
    
    .fas fa-times {
        display: none;
    }
    
    nav.active .fas fa-times{
        display: block;
    }
    
    nav.active .fas fa-bars{
        display: none;
    }
    
    nav.active .nav-list {
        display:flex;
    }
}

.hero-container {
    height: 100vh;
    background-image: linear-gradient(
    rgba(0,0,0,0.5),
    rgba(0,0,0,0.5)),
    url(../images/heroImage.jpg);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center;
    background-size: cover;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    
}

.hero-container span {
    color: white;
    font-size: 50px;
    letter-spacing: 0.2em;
    text-align: center;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    border: 10px solid white;
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 3px 14px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

.hero-container a {
    padding: 15px 16px;
    color: white;
    background-color: #1E90FF;
    height: 15px;
    border-radius: 5rem;
    transition: background-color 650ms;
}

.hero-btn:hover {
    color: black;
    background-color: yellow;
    transition: background-color 650ms;
}

.slide-container {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    height: 25vh;
    overflow: hidden;
    border: 5px solid #1E90FF;
    box-shadow: 0 16px 32px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 10px 30px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19);
}

.slide-container .slider {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 500%;
    height: 100%;
    float: left;
     /* animation: animate 30s linear infinite; */
    
}
    
.slide-container .slider .slide {
    position: relative;
    width: 20%;
    height: 100%;
    float : left;
}
    
.slide-container .slider .slide .caption{
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 60px;
    left: 60px;
    right: 60px;
    padding: 30px;
    background: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.slide-container .slider .slide .caption h2 {
    margin: 0 0 20px;
    padding: 0;
    color: white;
    font-size: 48px;
}

.slide-container .slider .slide .caption p {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    color: white;
    font-size: 18px;
}

.slide-container .slider .slide.business1 {
    background: url(../images/business1.jpg);
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center;
}

.slide-container .slider .slide.business2 {
    background: url(../images/business2.jpg);
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center;
}

.slide-container .slider .slide.business3 {
    background: url(../images/business3.jpg);
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center;
}

.slide-container .slider .slide.business4 {
    background: url(../images/business4.jpg);
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center;
}

.slide-container .slider .slide.canvas1 {
    background: url(../images/canvas1.jpg);
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center;
}

.slide-container .slider .slide.canvas2 {
    background: url(../images/canvas2.jpg);
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center;
}

.slide-container .slider .slide.canvas3 {
    background: url(../images/canvas3.jpg);
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center;
}

.slide-container .slider .slide.canvas4 {
    background: url(../images/canvas4.jpg);
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center;
}

.slide-container .slider .slide.embroidery1 {
    background: url(../images/embroidery1.jpg);
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center;
}

.slide-container .slider .slide.embroidery2 {
    background: url(../images/embroidery2.jpg);
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center;
}

.slide-container .slider .slide.embroidery3 {
    background: url(../images/embroidery3.jpg);
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center;
}

.slide-container .slider .slide.embroidery4 {
    background: url(../images/embroidery4.jpg);
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center;
}



@keyframes animate {
    0% 
    {
        left: 0;
    }
    
    20% 
    {
        left: 0;
    }
    
    25% 
    {
        left: -100%;
    }
    
    45% 
    {
        left: -100%;
    }
    50% 
    {
        left: -200%;
    }
    70% 
    {
        left: -200%;
    }
    75% 
    {
        left: -300%;
    }
    95% 
    {
        left: -300%;
    }
    100% {
        left: -400%;
    }
}

@media (max-width: 768px) {
    .slide-container .slider .slide .caption{
    bottom: 20px;
    left: 20px;
    right: 20px;
    padding: 20px;
    background: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.slide-container .slider .slide .caption h2 {
    margin: 0 0 10px;
    font-size: 30px;
}

.slide-container .slider .slide .caption p {
    font-size: 16px;
}

}

.slide-btn {
    text-align: center;
    width: 100%;
    height: 5rem;
    border: none;
    font-size: 20px;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    background-color: white;
    transition: background-color 650ms;
}

.slide-btn:hover {
    background-color: #1E90FF;
    cursor: pointer;
    transition: background-color 650ms;
}

.footer-row {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.footer {
    background-color: #1E90FF;
    padding: 70px 0;
    
}

.footer-container {
    max-width: 1170px;
    margin: auto;
}

li {
    list-style: none;
}

.footer-col {
    width: 25%;
    padding: 0 15px;
}

.footer-col h4 {
    font-size: 18px;
    color: white;
    text-transform: capatalize;
    margin-bottom: 35px;
    font-weight: 500;
    position: relative;
}

.footer-col h4::before {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    bottom: -10px;
    background-color: white;
    height: 2px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    width: 50px;
}

.footer-col ul li:not(:last-child) {
    margin-bottom: 10px;

}

.footer-col ul li a {
    font-size: 16px;
    text-transform: capatalize;
    color: white;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-weight: 300;
    color: white;
    display: block;
    transition: all 0.3s ease;
}

.footer-col ul li a:hover {
    color: yellow;
    padding-left: 8px;
}

.footer-col .social-links {
    display: inline-block;
    height: 40px;
    width: 40px;
    background-color: rgba(255,255,255,0.2);
    margin: 0 10px 10px 0;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 40px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    color: white;
    transition: all 0.5s ease;
}

.footer-col .social-links:hover {
    color: yellow;
}

@media (max-width: 767px) {
    .footer-col 
    {
        width: 50%;
        margin-bottom: 30px;
    }
    
}

@media (max-width: 574px) {
    .footer-col 
    {
        width: 100%;
    }
    
}
```

Comment: Can you use the Chrome developer tools to emulate the higher resolution and reproduce the issue?

Comment: You basic html structure is wrong, it's `<html><head></head><body></body></html>`

Comment: @Dejan.S I have PHP connected to it so it can go within my other files

Comment: @C.M. I think I got it fixed through the answer given below, I went into dev tools and gave it a super high width and it looks like it's working

Comment: I don't know PHP and what that means but I know that it probably will render the wrong way won't it? :)

Comment: @Dejan.S is correct, `<header>` should be inside the `<body>` - https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5492492/in-html5-can-the-header-and-footer-tags-appear-outside-of-the-body-tag

Comment: `<head>` is for meta data and stuff

Comment: Think of the `<body>` as the place for your content. The stuff that is rendered to the screen. `<header>` and `<footer>` are rendered and thus should be in `<body>`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use `.container-fluid` instead of `.container`: `.container` has one fixed width for each screen size; `.container-fluid` expands to fill the available width.

```css
*, *::before, *::after {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

body {
    overflow-x: hidden;
}

html {
    font-family: 'Montserrat', sans-serif;
    font-size: 12px;
}

a {
    text-decoration: none;
}

ul {
    list-style: none;
}

header {
    width: 100%;
    position: sticky;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    z-index: 999;
}

.container {
    width: 100%;
    max-width: 117rem;
    margin: 0 auto;
    padding: 0 1.5rem;
}

.menu-icons{
    color: #eee;
    font-size: 4rem;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    right: 2rem;
    transform: translateY(-50%);
    cursor: pointer;
    z-index: 1500;
    display: none;
}

nav {
    display: flex;
    align-items: center;
    width: 100%;
    height: 8rem;
    border-bottom: 1px solid rgba(225,225,225, 0.1);
}

.logo {
    display: flex;
    margin-right: 5rem;
}

.nav-list {
    display: flex;
    width: 100%;
    align-items: center;
}

.nav-list li {
    line-height: 8rem;
    position: relative;
}

.sub-menu li {
    line-height: 4rem;
}

.nav-list a {
    display: block;
    color: white;
    background-color: #1E90FF;
    padding: 0 1.5rem;
    font-size: 1.4rem;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    transition: color 650ms;
    transition: background-color 650ms;
}

.nav-list a:hover {
    color: black;
    background-color: yellow;
}

.cart {
    height: 30px;
    width: 40px;
    cursor: pointer;
    margin-right: 15px;
    margin-bottom: 5px;
}

.btn {
    padding: 1.3rem;
    display: inline-block;
    background-color: #1E90FF;
    border: 2px solid #1E90FF;
    border-radius: 5rem;
    transition: background-color 650ms;
}

.btn:hover {
    color: black;
    background-color: yellow;
}

.sub-menu {
    width: 20rem;
    display: block;
    position: absolute;
    border-top: 3px solid #00BFFF;
    z-index: 100;
    top: 16rem;
    transition: all 650ms ease;
    opacity: 0;
    visibility: hidden;
}

.sub-menu::before {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    top: -2.5rem;
    left: 3rem;
    border: 1.2rem solid transparent;
    border-bottom-color: #00BFFF;
}

.sub-menu .sub-menu::before {
    top: .9rem;
    left: -2.5rem;
    border: 1.2rem solid transparent;
    border-right-color: #00BFFF;
}

.sub-menu .sub-menu{
    border-top: none;
    border-left: 3px solid #00BFFF;
    top: 0;
    left: 160%;
}

.nav-list li:hover > .sub-menu {
    top: 8rem;
    opacity: 1;
    visibility: visible;
}

.sub-menu li:hover > .sub-menu {
    top: 0;
    left: 100%;
}
    
li.move-right {
    margin: auto 0 auto auto;
    line-height: initial;
    transition: color 650ms;
    transition: background-color 650ms;
}

@media screen and (max-width: 1050px) {
    .nav-list {
        position: fixed;
        top: 0;
        left: 0;
        height: 100vh;
        display:none;
        align-items: initial;
        flex-direction: column;
        background-color: #1E90FF;
        z-index: 1000;
        overflow-y: scroll;
    }
    
    .nav-list li {
        line-height: 6rem;
    }
    
    .sub-menu {
        position: initial;
        border: 3px solid transparent;
        border-left-color: #00BFFF;
        margin-left: 1rem;
        max-height: 0;
    }
    
    .sub-menu::before {
        display: none;
    }
    
    .nav-list li:hover > .sub-menu{
        opacity: 1;
        visibility: visible;
        max-height: initial;
    }
    
    li.move-right {
        margin: 0 auto 0 0;
        line-height: initial;
    }
    
    .menu-icons {
        display: block;
    }
    
    .fas fa-times {
        display: none;
    }
    
    nav.active .fas fa-times{
        display: block;
    }
    
    nav.active .fas fa-bars{
        display: none;
    }
    
    nav.active .nav-list {
        display:flex;
    }
}

.hero-container {
    height: 100vh;
    background-image: linear-gradient(
    rgba(0,0,0,0.5),
    rgba(0,0,0,0.5)),
    url(../images/heroImage.jpg);
    background-repeat: no-repeat;
    background-position: center;
    background-size: cover;
    background-attachment: fixed;
    
}

.hero-container span {
    color: white;
    font-size: 50px;
    letter-spacing: 0.2em;
    text-align: center;
    text-transform: uppercase;
    border: 10px solid white;
    display: inline-block;
    padding: 3px 14px;
    position: absolute;
    top: 50%;
    left: 50%;
    transform: translate(-50%, -50%);
}

.hero-container a {
    padding: 15px 16px;
    color: white;
    background-color: #1E90FF;
    height: 15px;
    border-radius: 5rem;
    transition: background-color 650ms;
}

.hero-btn:hover {
    color: black;
    background-color: yellow;
    transition: background-color 650ms;
}

.slide-container {
    position: relative;
    width: 100%;
    height: 25vh;
    overflow: hidden;
    border: 5px solid #1E90FF;
    box-shadow: 0 16px 32px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.2), 0 10px 30px 0 rgba(0, 0, 0, 0.19);
}

.slide-container .slider {
    position: absolute;
    top: 0;
    left: 0;
    width: 500%;
    height: 100%;
    float: left;
     /* animation: animate 30s linear infinite; */
    
}
    
.slide-container .slider .slide {
    position: relative;
    width: 20%;
    height: 100%;
    float : left;
}
    
.slide-container .slider .slide .caption{
    position: absolute;
    bottom: 60px;
    left: 60px;
    right: 60px;
    padding: 30px;
    background: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.slide-container .slider .slide .caption h2 {
    margin: 0 0 20px;
    padding: 0;
    color: white;
    font-size: 48px;
}

.slide-container .slider .slide .caption p {
    margin: 0;
    padding: 0;
    color: white;
    font-size: 18px;
}

.slide-container .slider .slide.business1 {
    background: url(../images/business1.jpg);
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center;
}

.slide-container .slider .slide.business2 {
    background: url(../images/business2.jpg);
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center;
}

.slide-container .slider .slide.business3 {
    background: url(../images/business3.jpg);
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center;
}

.slide-container .slider .slide.business4 {
    background: url(../images/business4.jpg);
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center;
}

.slide-container .slider .slide.canvas1 {
    background: url(../images/canvas1.jpg);
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center;
}

.slide-container .slider .slide.canvas2 {
    background: url(../images/canvas2.jpg);
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center;
}

.slide-container .slider .slide.canvas3 {
    background: url(../images/canvas3.jpg);
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center;
}

.slide-container .slider .slide.canvas4 {
    background: url(../images/canvas4.jpg);
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center;
}

.slide-container .slider .slide.embroidery1 {
    background: url(../images/embroidery1.jpg);
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center;
}

.slide-container .slider .slide.embroidery2 {
    background: url(../images/embroidery2.jpg);
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center;
}

.slide-container .slider .slide.embroidery3 {
    background: url(../images/embroidery3.jpg);
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center;
}

.slide-container .slider .slide.embroidery4 {
    background: url(../images/embroidery4.jpg);
    background-size: cover;
    background-position: center;
}



@keyframes animate {
    0% 
    {
        left: 0;
    }
    
    20% 
    {
        left: 0;
    }
    
    25% 
    {
        left: -100%;
    }
    
    45% 
    {
        left: -100%;
    }
    50% 
    {
        left: -200%;
    }
    70% 
    {
        left: -200%;
    }
    75% 
    {
        left: -300%;
    }
    95% 
    {
        left: -300%;
    }
    100% {
        left: -400%;
    }
}

@media (max-width: 768px) {
    .slide-container .slider .slide .caption{
    bottom: 20px;
    left: 20px;
    right: 20px;
    padding: 20px;
    background: rgba(0,0,0,0.5);
    box-sizing: border-box;
}

.slide-container .slider .slide .caption h2 {
    margin: 0 0 10px;
    font-size: 30px;
}

.slide-container .slider .slide .caption p {
    font-size: 16px;
}

}

.slide-btn {
    text-align: center;
    width: 100%;
    height: 5rem;
    border: none;
    font-size: 20px;
    letter-spacing: 1px;
    background-color: white;
    transition: background-color 650ms;
}

.slide-btn:hover {
    background-color: #1E90FF;
    cursor: pointer;
    transition: background-color 650ms;
}

.footer-row {
    display: flex;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
}

.footer {
    background-color: #1E90FF;
    padding: 70px 0;
    
}

.footer-container {
    max-width: 1170px;
    margin: auto;
}

li {
    list-style: none;
}

.footer-col {
    width: 25%;
    padding: 0 15px;
}

.footer-col h4 {
    font-size: 18px;
    color: white;
    text-transform: capatalize;
    margin-bottom: 35px;
    font-weight: 500;
    position: relative;
}

.footer-col h4::before {
    content: '';
    position: absolute;
    left: 0;
    bottom: -10px;
    background-color: white;
    height: 2px;
    box-sizing: border-box;
    width: 50px;
}

.footer-col ul li:not(:last-child) {
    margin-bottom: 10px;

}

.footer-col ul li a {
    font-size: 16px;
    text-transform: capatalize;
    color: white;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-weight: 300;
    color: white;
    display: block;
    transition: all 0.3s ease;
}

.footer-col ul li a:hover {
    color: yellow;
    padding-left: 8px;
}

.footer-col .social-links {
    display: inline-block;
    height: 40px;
    width: 40px;
    background-color: rgba(255,255,255,0.2);
    margin: 0 10px 10px 0;
    text-align: center;
    line-height: 40px;
    border-radius: 50%;
    color: white;
    transition: all 0.5s ease;
}

.footer-col .social-links:hover {
    color: yellow;
}

@media (max-width: 767px) {
    .footer-col 
    {
        width: 50%;
        margin-bottom: 30px;
    }
    
}

@media (max-width: 574px) {
    .footer-col 
    {
        width: 100%;
    }
    
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1.0, maximum-scale=1.0, minimum-scale=1.0">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="ie=edge">
    <link href="https://unpkg.com/ionicons@4.5.10-0/dist/css/ionicons.min.css" rel="stylesheet">
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="css1/styler.css">
    <script src="javascript/script.js" defer></script>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://use.fontawesome.com/releases/v5.15.3/css/all.css" integrity="sha384-SZXxX4whJ79/gErwcOYf+zWLeJdY/qpuqC4cAa9rOGUstPomtqpuNWT9wdPEn2fk" crossorigin="anonymous">
    <link rel="preconnect" href="https://fonts.gstatic.com">
    <link href="https://fonts.googleapis.com/css2?family=Montserrat&display=swap" rel="stylesheet">
    <header>
        <div style="background-color: #1E90FF;" class="container-fluid">
            <nav>
                <div class="menu-icons">
                    <i class="fas fa-bars"></i>
                </div>
                <a href="index.php" class="logo">
                    <img class="logo" src="images/logo_trans.png" alt="logo" style="height: 75px;">
                </a>
                <ul class="nav-list">
                    <li>
                        <a href="#">Home</a>
                    </li>

                    <li>
                        <a href="#">Services
                            <i class="fas fa-sort-down"></i>
                        </a>
                        <ul class="sub-menu">
                            <li>
                                <a href="#">Business Printing</a>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <a href="#">Canvas Printing</a>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <a href="#">Embroidery</a>
                            </li>
                            <li>
                                <a href="#">Signs</a>
                            </li>
                        </ul>
                    </li>

                    <li>
                        <a href="#">Partners</a>
                    </li>

                    <li>
                        <a href="#">About Us</a>
                    </li>
                    
                    <li>
                        <a href="#">Contact Us</a>
                    </li>
                    
                    <li class="move-right">
                        <img class="cart" style="float: right;" src="images/new_cart.png" alt="Cart">
                    </li>
                    
                
                </ul>
            </nav>
        </div>
    </header>
    <script src="javascript/script.js"></script>
</head>
<body>
```

Comment: Alright, I put it in the code I'll try it when I'm home, thank you very much.