# HTML being changed in, footer being placed inside the body when coded outside the body

Tags: html, python-3.x, web-scraping, request, urllib

I'm just doing a personal project and learning about HTML.
I've got a basic HTML script (full)

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
    <head>
        <title>Frame_Test</title>
    </head>
    <body>
        <p>PARAGRAPH FRAME</p>
    </body>
    <footer>
        <p>Paragraph Footer</p>
    </footer>
</html>
```

When i run the script, the footer is moved inside the body `<body><footer></footer></body>`. However when i do a `fp = urllib.request.urlopen(url)`it shows the footer being outside the body.
If the footer is outside the body the xpaths don't work. How do i fix this? I want to be shown the exact HTML code that is going to be shown to the user.

I am using HTML 5.
I have also used the request.get tool too and the results are the same

Edit:
When you compile the HTML file you are given this.

```
<!doctype html>
    <html lang="en">
        <head>
            <title>Frame_Test</title>
        </head>
        <body>
            <p>PARAGRAPH FRAME</p>
        <footer>
            <p>Paragraph Footer</p>
        </footer>
        </body>

    </html>`
```

Comment: I don't understand, where's the problem? The `<footer>` is outside of `<body>`?

Comment: if you try to compile it, it is placed inside the body. So compilation is different to the source code

Comment: What do you mean by *compilation*? Do you mean parsing?

Comment: @AndrejKesely when you run the code a.k.a when you try and open the website on chrome. I've pasted the HTML code that is shown on my chrome browser. You can see that the footer positioning has changed.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

That's on purpose. The <footer> tag can only be used inside the <body> tag.

Comment: Why? My code still compiles and i've seen examples of where the footer is outside the body tag

Comment: @WorkerBee Sure, it works. But as you saw, the footer ends up in the body tag. That's not by accident. HTML5 has a lot of implicit coercions that allow certain elements to work outside of their proper places or even for start and end tags to be emitted in specific situations. 

However, the body tag contains the main content of the document which includes the header and footer tag.

For more information, look at [this](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5492492/in-html5-can-the-header-and-footer-tags-appear-outside-of-the-body-tag) question.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation @Jimmy what tool can i use to get the HTML that is being shown to the user? That's the main issue i was being faced with. I've tried urllib and request

Comment: @WorkerBee That's beyond my experience of HTML. Maybe someone else has answered that in a different question. Or you can ask that yourself if no one else has.